# CDK 3.7.0 failing to start

Tags: minishift

I hit the following error, when I try to start CDK/minishift:

```
➜  bin ./cdk-3.7.0-1-minishift-linux-amd64 start    
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Check if deprecated options are used ... OK
-- Checking if https://mirror.openshift.com is reachable ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.43' is valid ... FAIL
```

Any clue how to solve it?

Comment: There is a workaround for it `minishift config set skip-check-openshift-release true`

Comment: Still an issue with latest download as of 2019-07-22

Comment: Hi @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, did you try to download the latest CDK? It is fixed in 3.9.0 (the latest release)

Comment: Official download page not updated from 3.7.0 yet.  https://developers.redhat.com/products/cdk/hello-world#fndtn-windows

Comment: You are right. Good catch :-). I filled an issue for that - https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DEVELOPER-5935. If you look at the Download page https://developers.redhat.com/products/cdk/download you should see the latest one 3.9.0 available for download

Comment: I gave up on minishift.  It does not appear to have enough focus as opposed to OpenShift.

Answer (score 3):

Code change inside CDK is needed. Therefore I'm looking forward to next version of CDK.

For more information, please see --> [CDK workaround for failing OpenShift version check](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/03/11/workaround-red-hat-container-development-kit-v3/) and [[CDK-397] OCP preflight check uses docker v1 API which is no longer available](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDK-397)